Tint Transmission Colour
I need to reproduce a material in Blender that was originally made in C4D.
The material is quite simple, but there's something I'm not able to translate from the two softwares. C4D has a colour input for Transmission, but Blender doesn't. What happens is that on C4D (which is the OG version of this material) the transmission uses a brighter hue of the diffuse colour for the transmission.

I don't expect the material to look exactly the same in both softwares, but I'm struggling to get closer to that transmission values I see on the Suzanne on the left, with that brighter purple.
How should I approach this?

Blender does have transmission, it's inside principle BSDF node

Yeah, I have transmission on in the example I shared. I guess what I'm asking is:

Blender has Transmission in the Principled BSDF node, with a value from 0 to 1.
Cinema has both the Transmission value and the Transmission colour. That's what is not available in Blender, and that's what I'd like to emulate in some way.


You could use the Light Path > Is Transmission Ray connected to a Mix node, itself connected to the diffuse color. The difference between the 2 examples of C4D are so similar that I don't really know what color to put exactly.

Layer weight connected to a color ramp could be a starting point. Also remember that the Render engines are different between C4D and Blender so you will notice some differences

Try plugging a brightened version of your base color into the SubSurfaceScattering color input?

HI Jakemoyo! Subsurface Scattering doesn't have a color input anymore :-/
